# Deflection of light by the Sun

Tags: general-relativity, astronomy

Can you give details of a recent experiment of deflection of light by the Sun?

What is the distance from the surface of the Sun and what is the exact value of the angle of deflection?

Comment: [this link provides an analysis of light deflection calculations in GR](http://lacosmo.com/DeflectionOfLight/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the Wikipedia article on [Tests of General Relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity#Deflection_of_light_by_the_Sun). The most recent measurement quoted there was by a group from the University of Texas. You can find [a copy of the paper here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1976AJ.....81..452B).

They measured a deflection of $1.66$ arcseconds $\pm 10\%$, compared to the prediction from General Relativity of $1.75$ arcseconds.

**Respond to comment:**

The angular deflection of the light at a distance $r$ from an object of mass $M$ [is approximately given by](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lensing#Explanation_in_terms_of_space.E2.80.93time_curvature):

$$ \theta = \frac{4GM}{c^2r} $$

Put in the mass and radius of the Sun and you'll find $\theta = 8.48 \times 10^{-6}$ radians. Convert this to degrees and multiply by $3,600$ to convert to arcseconds and you'll recover the figure of $1.75$ arcseconds I quoted above.

Comment: Is there specified the **distance** from the Sun? I couldn't find it. Should I assume it was just _grazing_ the surface , at 7c from the centre?

Comment: @bobie: yes, that's the angular deflection of a ray that just grazes the surface.

Comment: Aren't there any data relative to rays passing at a certain distance from the Sun? Do we know how the angle of deflection varies with distance?

Comment: @bobie: I've updated my answer to respond to your comment

Comment: That formula is theory, I was looking for different experiments at different distance. Probably when distance is greater tan R the angle of deflection is too small to be measured?...btw,.... isn't 4GM/c^2r the angle or rather *tangent* 'theta'?

Comment: @bobie: I don't don't know of experiments to measure $\theta$ as a function of distance. The 10% error in the paper I cited suggests you could make the measurements for $2r_{sun}$ or with some effort $3r_{sun}$. Beyond that would be hard.

Comment: @bobie: the equation I gave is an approximate equation that works when $\theta$ is small. At these small angles the difference between $\theta$ and $\tan\theta$ is negligable.